# Get notify before file is deleted

Tags: java, operating-system, jna

I am  using Java language 
What I want is that Can any one help me to write a code that
**When i click on delete option of any file or folder  I get notify before delete that I ma deleting a file Whether I want to continue ?**
I have seen many examples that notify after the file is deleted.
One thing I want to make clear is as I click on file placed  Desktop or My document directory I must get notify that

> You are deleting a file .do you want to continue ?

What I really need is I want the exact answer or code 
Please help
I shall be very thankful to you

Comment: Is this file deletion happening inside your program or outside of it (with windows explorer or something)?

Comment: File delete happen out side the program ie at desktop

Comment: Why would the user want your app. to do something their own OS is better at doing (and writing - given the 4 typos. in the two sentence message shown)?

Comment: actually this is the requirement of my project .please help me to do

Comment: *"actually this is the requirement of my project"*  You think that changes anything?  What if it was a requirement of your app. to strangle puppies?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible in Java. The operating system handles the file access, and another process is not capable of preventing the system denying access to those files. The only way you could do this is by having a file system written in Java (say, a loopback mounted WebDAV share) to which you could intercept the file requests with this kind of information. But not only would this be difficult to achieve, it also would only work if all of the access you are doing is via your loopback mounted system; it wouldn't work for files located on the disk or from other network shares.

So, in summary, you cannot do this with any programming language without writing your own filesystem and using that to intercept requests.